# Error while inserting Form in spring + hibernate + tomcat +mysql 5.0.1

Tags: mysql, spring, tomcat

when i try to restore client's Specific Table's into empty  Database,it restore the table successfully.
but when i run the application and try to insert the form its shows this error in browser like this[image]

and in Console it show this error [image]

can anybody tell me for what is this error is showing,and why am i getting .
i am using jvm version as 1.0.7 and my tomcat version is 6.0.32 .

thanks in advance

Comment: its ArrayIndexOutofBounds somewhere the array is getting out of bounds

Comment: bro anshulkatta ,indeed it is arrayindexoutofBound...its shows exception in console but y is it showing connection was reset in browser....

Comment: Could it be related to this bug? https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53677

Comment: @Bart yup may be, since every trace belongs to apache's class only !!

Comment: i have checked that link...wht do u suggest ,shell i try tomcat 7. or any other way is there

Comment: @viquar Tomcat7 will only handle the error better. Not solve it

Comment: so the bug i from tomact6 version right......nothing  wrong with my code .right @Bart

Comment: Check you request headers and see if it hold large amounts of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to increase **maxHttpHeaderSize** by setting it in `server.xml`

```
<!-- set maxHttpHeaderSize to 8kb -->
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
    connectionTimeout="20000" 
    redirectPort="8443"
    maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" />
```

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html

Comment: it dint work for 8k size,i tried with 24k then it worked ..thanks brother

Comment: I don't think there is one.